# How to mock Kotlin's kotlinx.android.synthetic views in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, android-testing

I have a fragment written in Kotlin. I import layout views using

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.my_fragment_layout.
```

In one of my methods I am setting the TextView's text:

```
fun setViews() {
    myTextView.text = "Hello"
    // In Java I would have used:
    // (getView().findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).setText("Hello");
}
```

In my plain JVM unit test, I want to test this method using Mockito.
For example, if the above method was written in java I could do:

```
public void setViewsTest() {
    // Mock dependencies
    View view = Mockito.mock(View.class);
    TextView myTextView = Mockito.mock(TextView.class);
    when(fragment.getView()).thenReturn(view);
    when(view.findViewById(R.id. myTextView)).thenReturn(myTextView);

    // Call method
    fragment.setViews();

   // Verify the test
   verify(myTextView).setText("Hello");
}
```

How can I do a similar implementation when using Kotlin's `kotlinx.android.synthetic` views?

Answer (score 2):

I think that [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) is a more proper tool for such type of tests. Using it you can have an easier way to test a code with Android dependencies on JVM.

For example, you test will look like something like this:

```
@Test
fun `should set hello`() {
    val fragment = YourFragment()

    fragment.setViews()

    assertEquals(fragment.myTextView.getText().toString(), "Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a solution for this problem too, and this is what I'm currently doing to mock views to be able to verify them.

This solution **does not** use `kotlinx.android.synthetic` since I haven't yet found a way to avoid the "Method not mocked" exception, instead I go with the `Butterknife` way.

In the activity or fragment:

```
@BindView(R.id.my_text_view)
internal lateinit var myTextView: TextView
// ...
fun setViews() {
    myTextView.text = "Hello"
}
```

In the test:

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.mock

class MyActivityTest {

    private val underTest = MyActivity()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        underTest.myTextView = mock()
    }

    @Test
    fun setViews() {
        underTest.setViews()

        verify(underTest.myTextView).text = "Hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is currently my solution too, but it doesn't truly answer the question. I really do wish it were possible to do this with ktx instead of Butterknife. Hopefully that functionality is added soon

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue.

Found that [Kotlin extension](https://www.raywenderlich.com/84-kotlin-android-extensions) adds some functionality to view/fragments.
Let's say - I have Fragment - SampleFragment, where onViewCreated() I'm accessing some views after inflation:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    with(webView) {
        webViewClient = createWebClient()
    }
}
```

Of course my unit test failed on webViewClient = createWebClient()

So, let's see what kotlin extension added to my fragment (go to Tools->Kotlin->Show Kotlin Byte Code and then select decompile).

```
public final class SampleFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    private HashMap _$_findViewCache;

    public View _$_findCachedViewById(int var1) {
      if (this._$_findViewCache == null) {
         this._$_findViewCache = new HashMap();
      }

      View var2 = (View)this._$_findViewCache.get(var1);
      if (var2 == null) {
         View var10000 = this.getView();
         if (var10000 == null) {
             return null;
         }

         var2 = var10000.findViewById(var1);
         this._$_findViewCache.put(var1, var2);
      }

      return var2;
   }
```

Now, we have HashMap that stores all our ids->Views key value pairs.
There are possible two solutions:
1. Spy your object and return correct view:

```
@Mock lateinit var view: View
@Mock lateinit var webView: WebView

@Before
fun setUp() {
    sampleFragment = spy(SampleFragment())
    doReturn(view).`when`(sampleFragment).view
    doReturn(webView).`when`(view).findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
}
```

2. Use reflection (mockito Whitebox) to initialize _$_findViewCache HashMap.

   var hashMap = java.util.HashMap()
   hashMap.put(R.id.webView, webView)
   Whitebox.setInternalState(sampleFragment, "_\$_findViewCache", hashMap)

May be there is another more Kotlin specific way to avoid this issue?